# Batch requests on the Google Plus API

Tags: http, google-api, google-plus

I am using the [Google + HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) to make many requests to the [people/get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) endpoint. This turns out to be quite slow, since it requires an HTTP request for each user ID.
It is not mentioned in the documentation, but is there any way to make batch requests on the Google Plus API?
Alternatively, any optimisation hints for this use case are very welcome.

Comment: From google developer guide https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/batch

Comment: Google+ is not included in the Google Data APIs: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory

Comment: It's the same batch semantics AFAIK. If you're using the Java client library Batch is supported well, same with Python.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/gdata/ : "The API Directory lists of all of the Google APIs that use the Google Data Protocol." Google+ is not one of those, which implies that it does not implement the Google Data protocol.

Comment: You mentioned the Java client library, it does indeed seem to have the wanted behaviour; testing it now, I will post an answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make batched requests on the Google+ API via the [Google APIs Java client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).

Here is a code sample:

```java
BatchRequest batch = plus.batch();

Get me = plus.people().get("me");
Get angularJS = plus.people().get("110323587230527980117");

BatchCallback<Person, GoogleJsonErrorContainer> cb = new BatchCallback<Person, GoogleJsonErrorContainer>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Person person, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) 
      throws IOException {
    System.out.println("batch success");
    System.out.println(person.getDisplayName());
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(GoogleJsonErrorContainer e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
      throws IOException {
    System.out.println("batch failure");
  }
};

batch.queue(me.buildHttpRequest(), Person.class, GoogleJsonErrorContainer.class, cb);
batch.queue(angularJS.buildHttpRequest(), Person.class, GoogleJsonErrorContainer.class, cb);

batch.execute();
```